# Bean validation - validate optional fields

Tags: spring, spring-boot, bean-validation

Given a class that represents payload submitted from a form, I want to apply bean validation to a field that may or may not be present, for example:

```
class FormData {
    @Pattern(...)
    @Size(...)
    @Whatever(...)
    private String optionalField;

    ...
}
```

If `optionalField` is not sent in the payload, I don't want to apply any of the validators above, but if it is sent, I want to apply all of them. How can it be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

So usually all of these constraints consider `null` value as valid. If your optional filed is `null` when it's not part of the payload all should work just fine as it is.

And for any mandatory fields you can put `@NotNull` on them.

**EDIT**
here's an example:

```
class FormData {
    @Pattern(regexp = "\\d+")
    @Size(min = 3, max = 3)
    private final String optionalField;

    @Pattern(regexp = "[a-z]+")
    @Size(min = 3, max = 3)
    @NotNull
    private final String mandatoryField;
}

@Test
public void test() {
    Validator validator = getValidator();

    // optonal field is null so no violations will rise on it
    FormData data = new FormData( null, "abc" );
    Set<ConstraintViolation<FormData>> violations = validator.validate( data );
    assertThat( violations ).isEmpty();

    // optional field is present but it should fail the pattern validation:
    data = new FormData( "aaa", "abc" );
    violations = validator.validate( data );
    assertThat( violations ).containsOnlyViolations(
            violationOf( Pattern.class ).withProperty( "optionalField" )
    );
}
```

You can see that in the first case you don't get any violations as the optional field is `null`.  but in the second exmaple you receive a violation of pattern constraint as `aaa` is not a string of digits.

Comment: @Mister_L Does that clarify the answer ? I've edited and added an example for you

Comment: What happens if the type is int and I want to use Min and Max validators for instance?

Comment: Since `int` cannot be `null` it cannot be treated as "optional" in the same manner... you can either change to `Integer` that allows `null`s or if you are forced to use `int` you might want to look into validation groups.